# Upgrading sugarcrm from 5.2 to latest

Tags: linux, sugarcrm

I need to upgrade from sugarcrm 5.2 to the most recent.

It keeps breaking on the process and I never got passed the 5.5, maybe 6 once.

Is it possible for me to just **install** the latest version of sugarcrm, and apply the Upgrade SQLs on the DB **only** and then use the fresh install with the upgraded DB?

Thanks

[EDIT]
I tried silent upgrades and every other way to upgrade the code, I have checked php settings etc, What I want to know is if I can do what I suggested above.
I also have cache/upload with 16GB of data and cache/images with a few more GB. What should I do with those folders in case I can get a fresh install and upgrade the DB?
[/EDIT]

don't know if it matters but my server runs Linux. (I don't think versions play a major rule on what I want to do, since I would only install most recent then I need up to date mysql, php, apache etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try using the silent upgrader, which sometimes is more successful...

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/05_Sugar_Community_Edition/Sugar_Community_Edition_6.5/Sugar_Community_Edition_Installation_Guide_6.5.0#Using_the_Sugar_Silent_Upgrader

From that far back, a migration may be a better option. You can simply install the new version, and then dump your old data into the new data structure.

Comment: well, I didn't mention here but I tried everything...
my problem also is that I have 16GB in the cache/upload folder and another few GBs in the cache/images.

What do you mean by dump your old data into the new data structure? the data structure is totally different (I hope at least, since the one in the 5.2 is really against any good sense in DB terms)

Comment: The database structures haven't changed much, so you should be able to point your new install at your old database, do a Quick Rebuild and Repair, and be up and running.

Comment: I took a look at the SQLs and I think it's a bit different than what you are saying... :-)

I'm again trying silent upgrade, and again I'm getting this error from 5.5.1 to 6.0.4 (all my settings are way above the necessary)
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class SugarLogger in /var/www/sugarcrm/include/SugarLogger/SugarLogger.php

and

Fatal error: Call to a member function info() on a non-object in /var/www/sugarcrm/include/database/DBManagerFactory.php on line 84

Comment: Can you search your instance for 'SugarLogger.php' and let me know what you find?